# Refactoring a similar controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I used Pull Review for reviewing my app's code and it came back with this:

> Consider refactoring, similar code detected.
>
> Occurred at:
>
> SkillsController # index
>
> PagesController # index

So the app/controllers/skills_controller.rb index action code is:

```
def index
  @skill = Skill.new
  if params[:search]
    @skills = Skill.search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC')
  else
    @skills = Skill.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

and on app/controllers/pages_controller.rb is:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC')
  else
    @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

Am I suppose to somehow refactor these two actions on these two controllers? Also, I am not sure how I refactor this. Do I extract the if params[:search] segment and replace the instance variables with another variable that will be used on both actions?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: globally it's telling you that both these methods are very similar and that you could probably extract some common code; on a side note, on first glance it seems you have a mistake in your code with `@users = Skill.all.order('created_at DESC')` which should probably be `@users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')`, and which might encourage your tool to think it's duplicated code. (note: I have no knowledge of Ruby syntax at all)

Comment: thanks for noticing the error

Comment: To be noted also that the `@users = User.all` line in the second code sample seems unnecessary - not knowing the syntax it looks like a variable assignment - considering both the `if` and the `else` parts also have a `@users = ...` statement (but that may be just me missing something by not knowing the syntax) -- the `@skill = Skill.new` in the first segment doesn't seem much used either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where your method `search` comes from. It seems it comes from a custom module/gem for ActiveRecord.

If so, you can change the method to shorten code in controller

```
def self.search(args)
  return self unless args
  original_search_logic args
end

# As well as extract order to a scope
scope :by_time, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

Then in controller:

```
# Skill
def index
  @skills = Skill.search(params[:search]).by_time
end

# User
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search]).by_time
end
```

These should be dry enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the has_scope and inherited_resources. You can extract the params[:search] part with has_scope. And use inherited_resources to extract how to get the collection and do the ordering.